# How to create a custom directive in angular

Tags: angular

i have been writing an application in angular and i am getting to grips with most stuff pretty well.
One thing i don't understand is structural directives or anything that uses code changes the DOM

For the simplest example of what I'm looking to learn, in a parent template if i have

```
<div [addTitle]='sometitle'>
   <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

i want to build a directive that when i add a div with [addTitle]='sometitle' attribute it alters the final code to this

```
<div [addTitle]='sometitle'>
   <h2>sometitle</h2>
   <child-component></child-component>
</div>
```

whilst keeping the content of `<child-component></child-component>` unaltered and with all the bindings within intact etc.

i know i need a  file such as

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[addTitle]'
})
export class addTitleDirective {
  constructor() { }
}
```

i just don't known how to access the inner 'html' of the tag with the directive on it or keep the child-component from being destroyed or how to add the `<h2>sometitle</h2>` to the DOM or show the  html that is inside the `<child-component>` back to the DOM

im sorry if this is to general but i am looking for some pointers to help me get started.

*edit*
inorganik has kindly pointed out that a component is more suited and given example ..thank you.

i was wondering if i had

```
<div [addTitles]="['sometitle1', 'sometitle2']">
   <child-component1></child-component1>
   <child-component2></child-component2>
</div>
```

and wanted to end up with

```
<div [addTitle]="['sometitle1', 'sometitle2']">

   <h2>sometitle1</h2>
   <child-component1></child-component1>

   <h2>sometitle2</h2>
   <child-component2></child-component2>

</div>
```

would a component still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `ng-content`. Also I think your example would be better served by a component than directive - So your component might look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-title',
  templateUrl: './title.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./title.component.scss'],
})
export class TitleComponent {

  @Input() addTitle: string;

}
```

template:

```
<h2>{{ addTitle }}</h2>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Then you use it like this:

```
<app-title [addTitle]="'my title'">
  <child-component></childcomponent>
</app-title>
```

Comment: I would also mention that we can use attribute selector `[addTitle]` for component just to not introduce a new element